# Convert coordinates to String

Tags: android

In my app i have got a lot of coordinates like this:

```
String uri ="uber://action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff[latitude]=
59.936435&dropoff[longitude]=30.296409&dropoff[nickname]=Place1";
```

How i can update them with Parse.com? Maybe i need to make String with this coordinates, that can be updated with Parse.com?

Also i have got coordinates google maps:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(59.624895, 30.230149)).title("Palce3"));
```

How i can update them?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Geocoder` object. Try this:

```
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(your_latitude, your_longitude, 1);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
```

Notice that Internet connection is required for `Geocoder` to work.